# Open a chrome profile in python that is already signed into google

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to open up my chrome profile which is signed into google however am not having any luck.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-
dir=G:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 10')
chrome_path= r"G:\Users\Kareem\Documents\Work\Computer 
Science\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?source=search_app")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `driver`, you're not actually passing the options to it.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: i added that sorry missed that in the code. When it opens the new tab and i click manage people it says default and guest not all my chrome profiles. And in chrome version it has the path i put plus default. Basically am trying to get it to open my normal chrome profile that is signed into google and specific websites so that i can use automation